# Currency symbol using sprintf$()

Tags: baan, infor-ln

Is there a way to format variables of type double with a currency symbol using [`sprintf$()`](http://www.baanboard.com/programmers_manual_baanerp_help_functions_formatting_io_sprintf) and round to the nearest hundredth or thousandth? Also can you do some arithmetic within the `sprintf$()`?

I was trying something like `sprintf$("formatting code goes here", (a*b))` but I didn't know what formatting code i needed to include

Comment: there is no `sprintf$` in C\

Comment: You don't need any special formatting code for the currency symbol. Just put it in the format string like any other fixed text.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the POSIX [`strfmon()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strfmon.html) function?  It can cope with most variations on how to format currency values.

Comment: My apologies. I was under the impression that the baan language was like a mix of c and sql

Comment: @web-dev: the Baan 3GL programming language is quite far from C. The manual can be found here: http://www.baanboard.com/programmers_manual_baanerp

Answer (score 1):

You can format `double` values rounded to the nearest hundreth with:

```
   char buf[32];
   double price = 12.99;
   snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.2f €", price);
```

You can control the number of decimal places with the *precision* field after the `.`. Use `%.3f` for 3 decimal places.